# Android getDir returns null

Tags: android, file, nullpointerexception

My code:

```
public class StorageHelper {
public static File getFileDir(Context context, String folder) {
    File sdDir = null;
    boolean sdCardExist = Environment.getExternalStorageState().equals(
            android.os.Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED);
    if (sdCardExist) {
        sdDir = context.getExternalFilesDir(folder);
        Log.println(Log.ERROR, "ZGStorage", "using External storage");
    } else {
        sdDir = context.getDir(folder, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        Log.println(Log.ERROR, "ZGStorage", "using Internal storage");
    }
    return sdDir;
}
```

If there would be any problem with this code ? because calling `getFileDir()` gets null on some devices,but works normally in most cases.

Comment: Do you have any stacktrace?

Comment: @Christopher  calling StorageHelper.getFileDir(context,"folder") just gets null

Comment: Which log messages is generated in that case?

Answer (score 0):

Do you have an external storage in your device (sdcard)? In this case add the following permissions to your Manifest:

```
android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE 
android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE
```

Answer (score 0):

You can test it once after restarting the device.
Sometimes after attaching/detaching device for USB Debugging it creates problem.